# how to use Gson to resolve the same field but different types of JSON

Tags: java, android, json

```html
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "type": "image", 
            "data": {//data at here is Object
                "attachment": "picurl", 
                "width": 600, 
                "height": 398
            }
        }, 
        {
            "type": "text", 
            "data": "聊过往，聊里"//data at here is String type
        }
    ]
}
```

how can i make the class to express this json with gson?

i try to make the class to express it but fail.

Answer (score 0):

please follow below structure code . change datatype according to structure

```
package Trans;

import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    List<Contents> contentsList;
    String type;
    String data;
    public List<Contents> getContentsList() {
        return contentsList;
    }
    public void setContentsList(List<Contents> contentsList) {
        this.contentsList = contentsList;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}

class Data
{
    String attachment;
    int height;
    int width;

    public String getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }
    public void setAttachment(String attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }


}

class Contents
{
    String type;
    List<Data> dataList;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
    public void setDataList(List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tool may be of some help to you

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/